# Arithmetic Time and Work related question

Tags: arithmetic

8 men can complet a piece of work in 20 days. 8 women can do the same work in 32 days. In how many days will 5 men and 8 women together will complete the same work?

All I have is:

Men's one day work = 1/20

Women's one day work = 1/32

Together, 5/20 + 8/32 = 1/2

But 2 days is the wrong answer. The correct answer is 16.

How are these types of questions solved? What is the general trick and mental picture to form?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the 8 men and 8 women.

A man's work in 1 day: 1/160.

A woman's work in 1 day: 1/256.

Then continue using your method.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! And what is the general idea behind these types of questions?

Comment: I think you already got the general idea. I would just do what you did.

Comment: The general idea is that _rates_ of "work completed" can be added together.  You want to use the information given to find the rate at which each individual could complete the task, expressed as $ \ \frac{1 \ \text{(for the entire task)}}{\text{number of time units}} \ $ , the time unit often being days in these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ratio of efficiency of men to women = (8*32)/(8*20) = 8:5
Total work for women = 8*32
5 men will be equal to = 5*8/5 = 8 women
so in 2nd case total women = 8 women + 5 men = 8 women + 8 women = 16 women
number of days required = d
so d*16 = 8*32
d = 16 days